# no access to delete files within /tmp

Tags: 12.04, command-line, drupal

I've deleted a similar posting I made to clarify this issue so it's not a double post.

my /tmp folder is full of random files. My actual storage space is fine but because there literally hundreds of thousands of these little files, before long I'll get errors due to the sheer number of files.

I've tried various options like running cron and various `sudo rm file*` but after I installed Midnight Commander and tried to delete, I received this note:

***"shell commands will not work when you are on a non-local file system"***

So, how do I get local? I've been trying via the Terminal command line on Mac, then I tried all the same things via VMWare but no go. I tried straight Linux commands as well as using Midnight Commander. With the pure Linux I had no errors nor indication that `rm` wasn't working until I ran another `ll` commmand and saw the files so at least I received that note above from Midnight Commander.

My permissions are set the same as the testing/dev server which is identical to the live server where I'm having problems but its /tmp folder is clean.

Comment: Odds are that those files are created by a different user. please update your question to include the relevant output of: ls -l /tmp

Comment: @ImaginaryRobots Given that there are 100,000s of files, the output of `ls -l /tmp` will be huge. Kelly please use this command to count the number of files per owner: `sudo find /tmp -type f -printf '%u\n' | sort | uniq c`

Comment: @zwets: correct. But, I added five lines to show but they didn't 'stick' to this post. I ran your snippet but it first said "Nouniq: c: No such file or directory" but asked for password, thought a moment and then just returned the prompt w/no other info? Regardless, I just noticed the permissions on the /tmp folder has "1777" if that indicates anything.

Comment: ok, I changed the permission on that /tmp folder to 755 and now I can delete files. However, I can only delete if I specify at least five characters.. so sudo rm filea* works but sudo rm file* doesn't. I may be on my way!

Comment: You sure that file* exists at all? Also, your `/tmp` should be cleaned at boot (normally) so just reboot your system and be done with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the usual permission bits for the /tmp directory are `1777`. The leading `1` indicates that the directory's [sticky bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) has been set, which means that although multiple users may write to the directory, they retain ownership of any files written there so that only they (or root) may delete them. Hence without `sudo` you will only be able to delete your own files from /tmp. As well, some files in /tmp may be open and/or locked by other processes and you should not attempt to delete them unless you know the locks are 'stale' - you can check for open files with `lsof` e.g.

```
$ sudo lsof +d /tmp
```

to see any open files at the top level of the directory, or

```
$ sudo lsof +D /tmp
```

to show open files anywhere in /tmp and its subdirectories - see the `OUTPUT` section of the lsof manpages `man lsof` for an explanation of what the various columns mean.

The second issue you are likely facing is that although commands like `rm` can take multiple filename arguments (including expanded wildcards or *shell globs*), there is a limit to the allowed length of the argument list. For example, if we create 100,000 files in `/tmp`

```
# touch /tmp/file{000000..099999}
# ls /tmp/file* | wc -l
100000
```

(so far so good) but if we add a further 100,000 files, the expanded shell glob (i.e. the list of files to be deleted) becomes too long for the `ls` command line

```
# touch /tmp/file{100000..199999}
# ls /tmp/file* | wc -l
-bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long
0
```

and similarly we can't delete in one go with `rm`

```
# rm -f /tmp/file*
-bash: /bin/rm: Argument list too long
```

The solution is to break down the wildcard list into manageable subsets - you did that manually, but it is possible to do it automatically using the `xargs` command e.g.

```
# echo /tmp/file* | xargs rm -f
```

You could also have used the `find` command with a `-exec` or `-execdir` action and the `{} +` argument replacement syntax - from `man find`

```
-exec command {} +
              This  variant  of the -exec action runs the specified command on
              the selected files, but the command line is built  by  appending
              each  selected file name at the end; the total number of invoca-
              tions of the command will  be  much  less  than  the  number  of
              matched  files.   The command line is built in much the same way
              that xargs builds its command lines.  Only one instance of  `{}'
              is  allowed  within the command.  The command is executed in the
              starting directory.
```

for example

```
# find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -name 'file*' -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

although the `xargs` version will likely be faster if you only need to delete from the top level of `/tmp` (i.e. not from any subdirectories).

If the directory continues to fill up you should really investigate which users / processes are creating the files and why. If you changed `/tmp`'s permissions you should reset them to `1777`.

Comment: Great explanation! The issue now is that though all the files are gone, when I ll I get:

drwxr-xr-x  3 coname www-data 34484224 Oct 10 13:00 tmp

That 3 mil is still there though there are actually only 4 files. Also, this is the folder that Drupal is using for temp files. I've checked all the Drupal settings and they are fine. Now it seems the server is 'remembering' instead of 'thinking'...?

Comment: ...ps... how does one render code in these comments? I tried the tick marks and they just render?

Comment: Don't forget some files may be open / locked by other processes - I have edited my answer to mention the `lsof` command for listing open files.

Answer (score 0):

If `sudo rm -rf foldername` not working then follow below procedure

Check with command

```
which rm
```

then check the path. in my case it was `/bin/rm` then run command like

```
/bin/rm -rf foldername
```